# Подключение к postgresql js

Tags: javascript

Как подключиться к postgresql c помощью js ?

Comment: из ноды или браузера?

Comment: Желательно браузер но можно и ноду

Comment: Из браузера напрямую никак.

Comment: https://www.google.com.ua/search?newwindow=1&client=ubuntu&hs=cP9&ei=rt9RWqD-PObM6ASz5qfIDw&q=postgres+node+js+adapter&oq=postgres+node+js+adapter&gs_l=psy-ab.3..33i22i29i30k1.26201.31051.0.31126.24.23.0.1.1.0.158.2069.16j5.21.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..2.22.2067...0j46j35i39k1j0i67k1j0i46k1j0i203k1j0i20i263k1j0i22i30k1j0i22i10i30k1.0.E734DZHZMlQ и 
https://github.com/begriffs/postgrest